# Change group or permissions when a file is moved to a shared directory on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, samba, file-permissions

I've set up a Linux server accessible with `ssh` and Samba share.
Every user has his own folder `USER/` and a public folder `USER_public/`.
Permissions on the `USER_public/` are set up using `setfacl` in such way that
every new file created in that folder inherits permissions and ownerships from the parent directory (in this case, read and write permissions for others).

The problem I have is that files that are moved from `USER/` to `USER_public/`
do not inherit these permissions automatically.

Is there a way of making the moved (copied) files to inherit permissions from
the parent directory automatically.
I want to avoid users manually connecting via `ssh` and changing the permissions
using `chmod`.

Thank you.

Edit : `getfacl` output :

```
# file: user1_public
# owner: user1
# group: group1
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:super_group1:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rw-
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:super_group1:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rw-
```

Comment: Have you created the acl with `-d`? Also, please add the output of `getfacl` for the public directory.